# Avoid time expiration error with Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Rating is something very simple, intuitive and require no much thought from a user, especially when it's desgined as "stars" (in my case it's most known rating system from 1 to 5). This often contrasts with how ratings widgets are implemented - the most popular solutions are by using forms, or by using links. The latter is highly not recommended due to several problems, particularly with how Search Engines see the pages and links.

So I've chosen implenting rating widget by forms: from the technical point of view it consists of 5 "submit" buttons, and the action method simply assigns rating depending on which (1,2,3,4,5) submit button has been clicked by a user. I'm not using Ajax for the moment.

Simple? I hoped so. The problem occurs because of how PHP-Symfony2 (or generally, web languages) platform treats forms: when the form time expires, it won't be validated! From a user, or UX, point of view, it's a very, very bad thing - he or she clicks and expects rating to occur. I haven't see anywhere on the net a website (imagine for instance a Facebook with "Like" button) which displays a message like "token has expired, please resubmit the form".

How to deal with form expiration in cases like ratings, where a user should always submit a form like this, though validation is a process that shouldn't be (?) abandoned? Or should I ignore validation, at least in case of tokens?

Comment: @Alok For the moment, I do exactly what I wrote above: I display standard "form expiration" message and ask a user to resumbit it. But from UX point of view it feels very bad practice, and I haven't seen anything like that anywhere on the net. How do you deal with rating form expiration (assuming you're using forms for this)?

Comment: Instead of forms, you can use links with your rating (from 1 to 5), then display the links as buttons. This should avoid problems with tokens.

Comment: I updated the title of this question, it looks like rating is not the real problem (you may have the same problem with a text field, a *like* button, etc.). So mentioning the rating in the title may have been confusing.

Comment: @A.L Thanks, but using links is not recommended - of course unless ajax is being used. I wanted to avoid a solution with ajax, but I guess I have no choice; also google, amazon and others use make an instensive use of ajax for rating and other widgets. It's not democracy here on the web ;P

Comment: How much time pass before users see *token has expired, please resubmit the form*? Do you use a cookie to allow your users to stay connected?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when the sessions were persisted in the cache. Every time I updated the website and cleared the cache, the sessions were destroyed and the tokens were invalidated.

Now that the [sessions are stored in the database](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html) I haven't seen this problem. Here is the relevant configuration:

`app/config/config.yml`:

```
framework:
    session:
        # ...
        handler_id: session.handler.pdo

services:
    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        public:    false
        arguments:
            - 'mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%'
            - { db_username: '%database_user%', db_password: '%database_password%' }
```

And the `sessions` table has to been created, here is how to do it with a MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `sess_id` VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `sess_data` BLOB NOT NULL,
    `sess_time` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sess_lifetime` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL
) COLLATE utf8_bin, ENGINE = InnoDB;
```